# How to upgrade to Flutter 3.7?

Tags: flutter, unix, serverpod

I want to upgrade to Flutter 3.7 so I can start using [Serverpod](https://docs.serverpod.dev/) (which requires version 3.7). However when I perform `flutter upgrade` it says:

```
Flutter is already up to date on channel stable
Flutter 3.16.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 78666c8dc5 (2 weeks ago) • 2023-12-19 16:14:14 -0800
Engine • revision 3f3e560236
Tools • Dart 3.2.3 • DevTools 2.28.4
```

I ready that in order to upgrade to 3.7 you need to install Flutter Version Manager. So I did and this is the result:

```
dart pub global activate fvm
Package fvm is currently active at version 2.4.1.
The package fvm is already activated at newest available version.
To recompile executables, first run `dart pub global deactivate fvm`.
Installed executable fvm.
Warning: Pub installs executables into $HOME/.pub-cache/bin, which is not on your path.
You can fix that by adding this to your shell's config file (.bashrc, .bash_profile, etc.):

  export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"

Activated fvm 2.4.1.
```

But then when I perform `fvm install 3.7.16` it returns:

```
zsh: command not found: fvm
```

Why does it say command not found and how can I fix it?

Comment: `dart pub global activate fvm` command has written what to do, find `Warning: ...`

Comment: You can also use puro (for which I abandoned all prior use of fvm, because it's better, faster, less resource intensive).

Comment: Flutter 3.16.5 is newer than 3.7. 16 > 7. You should be good on this version.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does it say command not found and how can I fix it?

Quoting the output you got after activating the `fvm`:

```
Pub installs executables into $HOME/.pub-cache/bin, which is not on your path.
You can fix that by adding this to your shell's config file (.bashrc, .bash_profile, etc.):

  export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
```

Comment: I have added `export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"` to `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`, however am still getting the `zsh: command not found: fvm` error.

Comment: You are using zsh, put this in `.zshrc` and restart terminal